# Creating List Webpart: Ordering by Date field and Type

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am trying to create a web-part to show items that relate to a certain field and are before an expiration date using a web-part in SharePoint 2007.

The list has a **Title** field, a **URL** field a **Related** field and an **ExpireDate** field.

So the list looks like this:

```
Title       URL           Related  ExpireDate
Resolution  http://blah   Service  5/14/2013
Solution    http://blah2  Records  9/14/2012
```

So if I need the items that are related to service today's date is before the expiration date I want it to display.

Do I need a calculated Column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a view where **ExpireDate** is greater than or equal to [Today] And **RelatedField** contains Service.